# I have deleted most of my root directory with "sudo rm /*", and I don't know what to do

Tags: arch-linux, system-recovery

I'm on Arch Linux, and I intended to run "sudo rm ./*" to clear out one of old dirs, and I accidentally omitted the dot and ran "sudo rm /*".

How could I recover at least some of my old files?

Comment: The `/` directory should have no or few files in it, and your command does not cause a recursive deletion of subdirectories to happen. Are you sure that _anything_ got deleted?

Comment: By default arch has GNU `rm` installed which features a failsave for deleting `/`. Are you sure the command was executed as you assume?

Comment: @muru Nice catch. I wasn't aware of those symbolic links, but removing them would definitely cause a bit of havoc.

Comment: Next time begin your dangerous input with a `#` or an `echo`, when you've double checked your inputs you remove the `#` or `echo`, also don't type `./*` but type just `*`, or better, type the full path.